# Rails: Query with association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to gather all posts where `created_at <= Time.now`, `status = 0` and `dislikes < 3`. `created_at` and `status` is columns in the `Post` table, but `Dislike` is its own table. How can I access the amount of dislikes within the query (`Post` and `Dislike` is "connected" through has_many)?

I have this now, and it works:

```
@posts = Post.where("created_at <= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 0).order("created_at DESC")
```

How can I include the amount of dislikes in the query?

(The Dislike table consist of `:post_id` and `:user_id` and I can get the amount of dislikes on a post by writing `@post.dislikes.count`)

Answer (score 1):

There is at least two approaches to reach the goal:

Using `having` in your query

```
@posts = Post.joins(:dislikes).
  where("posts.created_at <= ? AND posts.status = ?", Time.now, 0).
  group("posts.id").
  order("posts.created_at DESC").
  having("COUNT(dislikes.id) < 3")
```

Use counter cache column (described in [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) episode)

```
@posts = Post.
  where("created_at <= ? AND status = ? AND dislikes_count < ?", Time.now, 0, 3).
  order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Try to use table name for `created_at` (`posts.created_at`). And could you provide execution result from first example?

Comment: Allright, tried with `posts.`. Here is the result: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "dislikes" ON "disl...`

Comment: Sorry for late response. Try to add `group("posts.id")` into the chain. I've updated my answer for first example.